# How can I extract a dict form from a string?

Tags: python

I got a string, it's like:

```
"{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}"
```

I want to assign a variable to this string and make the variable a dict.
It sounds easy, but I spend half hour and didn't figure it out. How to do it?

Comment: How do you get this string?

Comment: @thefourtheye, some result passed by other colleagues, this is a rather abstract form.

Comment: Can't you ask them to pass the data as key-value pairs?

Comment: Why aren't they just giving you the dict that you want?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, It's writing in a file, every item has a stinged dict

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ast.literal_eval()` function as follows:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}")
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

You could use it in a programme as follows:

```
import ast
dictString = "{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}";
dictFinal = ast.literal_eval(dictString)
print (dictFinal)
```

There is more help in the docs at this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: probably better not using `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: ahh right, was just coding off the top of my head